# How to skip Confirm in Bot Framework FormFlow and jump to change options when starting with saved data?

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a FormFlow dialog that allows the User to save the order. When the User comes back, would like to ask User to:

1. Re-Order
2. Change last order
3. Start fresh

1 and 3 are working as expected. 2 takes the user to a confirmation of last order where they can answer "no" to go ahead and change it, but this is an unnecessary step.

Question: what's the best way to show the user the step *after* the built in confirmation?

In other words, any ideas on how can I use FormFlow to take the User to the "What do you want to change" message that shows the form options with selected values?